# Can I use Linux ubuntu on Thin client hardware for accessing windows Terminal services?

Tags: thin-client

I am working on project to get thin client's and would like to get rid of the desktops. Ideally looking for a free thin client solution that will access the windows Terminal services. So anything an RDP session to the server, and I'm thinking Linux Ubuntu! Will it work without any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenThinClient](http://openthinclient.org/home) is a Free Open Source ThinClient Solution consisting of a Linux based operating system along with a comprehensive Java based management GUI and server component. It is intended for environments where a medium to large number of Thin Clients must be supported and managed efficiently. Offering flexibility unheard of in the world of proprietary Thin Client Solutions, openThinClient empowers developers and integrators to create advanced Thin Client solutions... for free.

Since it runs on Java it'll work on Windows, Unix, Mac...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on ubuntu, use Remmina to connect to a windows OS.
I use this at work, and Remmina works better than the windows rdp client.